# Erro ""AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" no Java ao tentar fazer IF

Tags: java

Estou fazendo uma condição na execução de uma pesquisa no Java, o que acontece é que não posso ter espaço em branco, asterisco(*) ou ponto de interrogação(?) como primeiro caractere da busca. Porém o Java está me retornando o seguinte erro quando deixo o campo em branco:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at main.Princ$4.actionPerformed(Princ.java:255)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Condição da linha 255:

```
        if (Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals(" ")
                || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals("")
                || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals("?")
                || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals("*")) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            panel,
                            "O campo de busca não pode estar vazio ou possuir \"?\", \"*\" ou espaço em branco como primeiro caracter.");

        } else {
            // executa a busca
        }
```

Comment: Isso não iria estourar da mesma forma? Pois se não tem char na posição 0, ao executar o método ele iria dar um throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, não?

Comment: @PauloRoberto como que sua sugestão na primeira linha evita a exceção? Ele vai continuar tentando acessar uma posição que não existe. A única resposta até agora responde a pergunta corretamente.

Comment: Opa, desculpem. Vou postar uma resposta melhor formulada e apagar meu comentário.

Comment: Postei uma resposta explicando melhor o que quis dizer, ficou bem simples @Strokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tamanho da sua String retornada pela operação `txtConteudo.getText()` tem tamanho `0`, e você tenta acessar seu primeiro elemento através do comando `txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)`, ou seja, você está tentando acessar um caractere além do último caractere válido. Na verdade você não possui nem sequer um caractere e tenta acessar o primeiro, logo uma exceção é lançada.

Percebi que você tentou fazer tal validação através de uma das condições do seu if:

```
Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)).equals("")
```

Mas a exceção é lançada antes mesmo da sua linha de código chegar até o `equals("")`, pois ela acontece no `charAt(0)`, portanto, essa linha não serve para nada. Ao invés disso, verifique o tamanho da sua String ANTES de tudo, e somente depois tente acessar seus caracteres.

Exemplo:

```
    if(txtConteudo.getText().length() == 0 //graças ao short-circuit não compara as demais se essa condição é falsa
       || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)).equals(" ")
       || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)).equals("?")
       || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)).equals("*")) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel,
           "O campo de busca não pode estar vazio ou possuir \"?\", \"*\" ou espaço em branco como primeiro caracter.");
    } else {
        // executa a busca
    }
```

Veja a documentação [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) e [String length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)

Comment: Testetesteteste

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que não existe nenhum char na posição 0, pois a String esta vazia. O que você tenque fazer é uma verificação antes, para ver se a String está vazia ou não.
Um possível exemplo:

```
if(txtConteudo.getText().length() > 0){
        if (Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals(" ")
                || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals("?")
                || Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0))
                        .equals("*")) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            panel,
                            "O campo de busca não pode estar vazio ou possuir \"?\", \"*\" ou espaço em branco como primeiro caracter.");

        } else {
            // executa a busca
        }
}else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( panel,
                                "O campo de busca não pode estar vazio.");
}
```

Comment: `length()`, pois é um método, não um atributo

Comment: desculpe, não testei o código, vou editar a resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: talvez tb fosse bom vc tirar a condição `.equals("")`, e colocar a msg de erro no else do primeiro if, entendeu o por quê?

Comment: Sim eu entendi, mas apenas fiz o if inicial, não fiz uma análise do código que o OP postou.

Comment: sim sim, só sugeri, inclusive achei q eu tava palpitando tanto na sua que acabei não aguentando e escrevi uma resposta tb, rs..

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver seu problema com verificação de operador ternário atribuído diretamente na variável, sendo assim, não tendo que converte-la e a acessa-la novamente à toda verificação, poupando código desnecessário e performance:

```java
//compare vai receber o txtConteudo na 0 se length for > 0 senão recebe ""
String compare = (txtConteudo.getText().length() > 0) ? Character.toString(txtConteudo.getText().charAt(0)) : "";
if (" ".equals(compare) || ("").equals(compare) || "?".equals(compare) || "*".equals(compare))
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "O campo de busca não pode estar vazio ou possuir \"?\", \"*\" ou espaço em branco como primeiro caracter.");
else
  // executa a busca
```

Veja como ficou simples, e também note que eu inverti a ordem do `equals()` para prevenir erros caso a variável à ser comparada fosse nula, é sempre melhor utilizar o `equals()` desta forma, prevenindo sempre `NullPointerException`'s