# Por que ocorre e como resolver um erro de "out of bounds" ou "out of range" ou algo de tipo?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, outofrange

Já vi erros e exceções do tipo "subscript out of range" ou "index out of bounds" ou alguma combinação de palavras assim. O que esse erro quer dizer e como costuma ser a forma de corrigi-los?

O mesmo vale para outros erros que não acham um elemento de uma coleção, por exemplo:

- Cannot read property 'xyz' of abc (Não é possível ler a propriedade 'xyz' de abc)
- AttributeError: 'abc' object has no attribute 'xyz'
- Undefined property: xyz::$abc
- KeyError: “['xyz'] not found in abc”
- NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
- coloque aqui a mensagem de erro da sua linguagem quando não achou um elemento

> a intenção é ter uma resposta canônica para usar em perguntas que não tem um problema exposto de forma bem específica, por isso se uma pergunta é geral sobre isso, uma resposta geral serve, então aqui já tem uma duplicata ou explicação do fechamento da pergunta e referência para a pessoa perceber o erro (possível de digitação).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Erro de programação

Antes de mais nada, esse é um erro de programação. É importante dizer isso porque costuma ser uma exceção em várias linguagens e as pessoas ficam tentadas em capturar a exceção e fazer alguma coisa. Isso é usar exceção para controle de fluxo, é deixar de validar algo que pode ocorrer de errado para só tratar se der o erro. Não faça isso, corrija o erro, mesmo que seja fazer a validação e dar o tratamento antes de dar o erro.

## O erro

Esse erro (não vou falar em exceção aqui, porque mesmo que seja lançada uma, ainda é um erro) ocorre apenas em **coleções de dados ou objetos compostos** que se comportam como coleções (algumas linguagens de tipagem dinâmica possuem composições implementadas como uma coleção, por exemplo uma classe ou algo parecido é implementada como um dicionário que é uma coleção).

Para acessar um elemento da coleção é preciso dizer qual é o elemento desejado, de alguma forma. Esta forma costuma ser chamada de **índice**, mas em alguns casos pode ser uma **chave**, e em inglês podem usar o termo *subscript*. Esse valor que indexa o elemento da coleção tende a ser um número, mas nada impede que seja outros tipos de dados, de fato em dicionários é comum ser *strings*.

## Tipos de coleções

Em algumas coleções os valores são sequenciais e formam uma faixa clara de dados, por exemplo começa em 0 e termina 9, possuindo uniformemente 10 elementos em sequência. Eles possuem uma forma de *array*, mesmo que não seja exatamente um. Em coleções mais livres podem ter índices/chaves (o termo mais usado nesses casos) esparsos, ou seja, os valores não estão de forma sequencial, então se forem números pode começar em qualquer número e terminar em qualquer outro e não precisa ter todos os números entre eles. O mesmo vale para *strings* ou outros dados como chave.

```cs
for (var i = 1; i <= lista.Count; i++) //erro aqui
for (var i = 1; i < lista.Count; i++) //certo
```

Uma *string* é uma coleção de dados, ela é uma sequência de caracteres geralmente começada no caractere de posição 0 e terminando no tamanho menos um. Não tente acessar um caractere que esteja fora desta faixa. É comum a pessoa tentar acessar sem querer fora desta faixa, talvez porque tentou fazer uma busca que não achou a informação (pode retornar -1).

Se considerar que uma tabela ASCII ou algo parecido é uma coleção, [pode ocorrer algo semelhante sem dar erro, só resultado ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261784/101). [Outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213908/101).

## Como ocorre o erro

Como é uma coleção, esse valor de índice/chave precisa existir nela, se não existir ocorre o erro descrito na pergunta ou alguma variante dele.

Em coleções normais como *arrays* o termo "faixa" (*range*) ou o uso de limites (*bounds*) de início e fim é mais usado porque ele certamente tem todos os números de uma faixa. O que você não pode fazer é acessar um número que esteja fora dessa faixa. Não é obrigatório começar em 0, mas se começar não pode usar um valor que seja negativo. E não pode acessar um valor que seja maior do que a quantidade de elementos. Então se começa com 0 não pode ser nem o número que indica o tamanho, nem um número maior que este. Porque se começa do 0, por exemplo se tiver 10 elementos, vai de 0 até 9, então o 10 já não é válido. Se começar em 1, então o 10 seria válido, mas o 11 não, e neste caso o 0 também seria inválido.

```js
let r = [2, 5, 6, 18, 20, 10, 23, 12, 19, 10];
let s = [1, 5, 7, 13, 18, 21, 10, 25, 32, 17, 3];
let x = [0];
let i;
console.log("i = " + i);
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    x[i] = r[i];
    console.log("i = " + i);
}
console.log("i = " + i);
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    x[i + 10] = s[i];
    console.log("i = " + i);
}
console.log("i = " + i);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/OutOfRange.js).

O erro pode indicar um valor fora da faixa para baixo ou para cima, não importa.

O erro ocorre de forma muito comum quando o índice que é usado é obtido numa fórmula ou é obtido por um dado externo que aquele algoritmo não tem controle. Ou ocorre quando vai acessar um elemento específico ou então quando faz um laço e este laço ou começa no número errado ou tenta terminar depois que já avaliou todos elementos que tinha que analisar.

É comum ocorrer em funções e métodos que tem um laço internamente, um caso muito comum é a `Substring()`.

Tem uma [classe que mostra superficialmente como o erro é gerado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126968/101).

## Como evitar

No caso do laço o ideal é usar uma construção da linguagem, se tiver que varrer toda coleção por controle próprio assim não tem muito como errar ([desde que a coleção não seja modificada em sua estrutura e não mude a quantidade de elementos existentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152521/101)). Pode ser um [`foreach` ou um `for`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278924/101) abstrato que faça isto. Quando usa um [`for` bruto ou `while`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/101) onde o programador controla onde deve parar, é que costuma acontecer o erro. O erro mais comum é a pessoa colocar a comparação verificando o fim se o contador é menor ou igual ao tamanho, mas se começa do zero tem que ser menor que o tamanho total da coleção.

```cs
foreach (var item in lista) WriteLine(item); //assim não tem como dar esse erro
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/OutOfRange.cs).

Há casos que está usando um laço mas não está acessando o elemento de forma direta, mas sim calculando o número usando o contador do laço como parte da fórmula. Este é um caso híbrido, o problema pode ser no limite do contador ou pode ser na fórmula. Por exemplo, se você usa uma fórmula que pega sempre o "contador mais um", obviamente não pode ir até o último valor possível na coleção porque o último possível mais um dá um número fora da faixa, por exemplo se a coleção vai de 0 a 9, o contador deve parar em 8, se for no 9 a fórmula resultará em 10 e dará o erro.

Então a solução para o problema é sempre validar certo quando deve parar, nunca deixar passar do número do elemento que não existe na coleção naquele momento. Nunca pressuponha que sabe quantos elementos tem ali, sempre pegue esse número ou use uma construção que garanta isso.

```cpp
if (n >= 0 && n < opcoes.size()) return opcoes[n]->reproduz();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/OutOfRange.cpp).

No caso do acesso ser feito individualmente por um dado calculado ou obtido externamente quase sempre é necessário validar o dado variável e que veio sem controle direto do seu algoritmo. Se não passar na validação de estar entre a faixa inicial (geralmente 0) e a final (geralmente o tamanho da coleção menos um), ou ainda se tem aquela chave, então deve fazer alguma operação alternativa, geralmente retornando um erro ou fazendo algo diferente (em alguns casos até pode lançar uma exceção, mas não costuma ser a melhor opção, mas se forma uma exceção mais específica em alguns casos pode ser interessante, só é mais raro ser o certo).

Só acesse um índice/chave condicionalmente, a não ser que seja 100% garantido que não tem como ser um dado inválido, mas são raros casos assim, como pode ser visto nos códigos e *links* postados aqui. Esta dica serve para qualquer dado, não só esses que são índices/chaves. Quase todos os *bugs* ocorrem porque algum dado não está no estado que está esperando e não pode confiar em nada.

Note que que vemos muito caso de erro em que a chave (de um dicionário ou objeto) não existe sem mesmo vir de finte externa, ou seja, é simples erro de digitação, é como se tivesse digitado o nome de uma variável errada no código.

E de fato muitas vezes em casos de literais usando como chave elas funcionam como se fossem nomes e variáveis mesmo. O elemento da coleção não deixa de ser uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

O uso de [`assert()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166719/101), [`requires()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347962/101) ou algo semelhante costuma ser uma boa ideia. Aprenda-os.

## Nem tudo gera erro

Algumas estruturas de dados não lançam erros ou exceções quando a chave não existe, apenas retornam um [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) que pode ser um nulo. Algumas tem [métodos que permitem escolher o que acontece quando tenta acessar uma chave não existente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332621/101). Cuidado pode parecer certo porque funciona, mas dará resultado ruim.

Tem linguagens que não dão erro, só ferra tudo. C e C++ em certa medida, são assim.

## Onde não dá erro

Se você não está passando uma posição em uma coleção de dados então o erro não acontecerá, então precisa de duas coisas: coleção de dados e posição sendo acessada. A posição pode ser passada por um operador indexador, muito comum ser colchetes `objeto[x]` (de um *array*, lista, ou dicionário), mas outras linguagens podem ter outras notações, JS pode fazer assim `objeto.x` e ainda é uma posição nessa coleção. Também pode ocorrer em métodos que recebem a posição de uma forma ou de outra, pode ser até um dado que será usado para calcular a posição.

## Averiguando o erro

Um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101) manual ou auxiliado pelo IDE (*debugger*) sempre indicará o que está acontecendo. Você executa passo a passo e analisa o valor do elemento sendo usado e verá que um dele logo no momento que dará o erro está acessando um índice/chave que não existe, por isso é preciso saber todas chaves possíveis ou a faixa do índice possível.

Lembre-se sempre de olhar o dado naquele momento, ele pode não ser o que deseja, pode não conter todos elementos que está esperando, isto pode ser a causa do erro. Se o dado estiver ok então seu algoritmo está pegando um valor que não devia.

Não tem milagre, não tem resposta fácil e rápida, tem que analisar o que está acontecendo. Faça a análise e aprenda programar melhor no processo. Aprenda a se virar por conta própria, você vai precisar. Quem não sabe fazer isso não sabe o básico de programação e acessar coleções está além da sua capacidade atual, repense o ritmo de aprendizado.

Esse é um erro chato pois sempre [ocorre em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332635/101) (existem poucas situações que poderia ser evitado em tempo de execução e nem costuma valer o esforço fazer isto).

## Extra

Não falei, mas já vi erros em que o valor sendo usado era um literal e portanto de total controle do algoritmo sendo escrito ali. Quase sempre o problema não está bem nesse algoritmo, está no dado recebido, provavelmente você esperava receber uma coleção de dados com um número determinado de elementos e por alguma razão não está recebendo isto. Provavelmente o problema está na criação do dado e deve concentrar os esforços em analisá-lo. Você pode melhorar seu algoritmo para lidar com um caso de erro assim, mas quase sempre o resultado melhor fazer o dado vir corretamente já que faz parte do contrato vir assim. Claro, isso pode não ser um bom *design*, não é robusto, ou para dar robustez complica o código e piora a performance, mas muita gente desenvolve sem pensar nessas coisas ("todos" que escolhem uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica). [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245363/101).

## Conclusão

De uma certa forma pode ser visto como uma variante da divisão por zero. Só ocorre porque está recebendo um valor que não é aceito naquele contexto. Não importa o que faça, a solução sempre está em validar implícita ou explicitamente o dado que será usado como índice/chave antes de usar, tem que ser garantido que ele existe (isso se não for erro de digitação).

[Exemplo em C# de código robusto para não deixar acessar um elemento que não existe inadvertidamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314158/101).

Exemplos de perguntas que falam deste erro, é quase certo que o seu está coberto em algum.

- [Var dentro do FOR quando começa em 0(zero) o Count deve ser Count-1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54115/101)
- [Como guardar letras em uma variável e exibi-las todas no final formando uma frase/palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148933/101)
- [Variável não designada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220446/101)
- [Quero salvar 3 números e depois imprimir na tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388491/101)
- [Meu programa feito em C++ fica em loop infinito, como corrigir?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321702/101)
- [Dúvida sobre closures, função dentro de loop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/404127/101)
- [Remover elemento de uma lista por chave (key) e por valor (value)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136225/101)
- [Laço de repetição com problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386206/101)
- [Lançamento de exceções em função de número primo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148017/101)
- [Como exibir um texto com múltiplas linhas com format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250994/101)
- [Listbox items out of range](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319732/101)
- [Erro ""AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" no Java ao tentar fazer IF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9896/101)

> Vou colocar mais exemplos, tentar usar mais linguagens, outras respostas podem ajudar mais pessoas