# Iteração GoogleAppScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Fiz o seguinte código para iterar e pegar o valor de duas colunas, B e E. Se "B" contiver o valor SIM e "E" estiver vazio, ele adiciona "1" ao contador, e devolve a soma no final. Porém, ao executar o código, dá o seguinte erro: Intervalo não encontrado (linha 12, arquivo "tste2")
A linha 12 está identificada no código. Nâo sei o que pode estar errado.

```
function toastAlerta() {
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var semEvid = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<23;i++){
    var resp = sh.getRange('B'+i).getValue(); //linha 12 
    var evid = sh.getRange('E'+i).getValue();
    if ((resp == 'SIM') && (evid == '')) {
      semEvid+=1;

    }
  }
Logger.log('Respostas sem evidencias: ' + semEvid);
}
```

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101

Comment: Estou vendo. Grato.