# Caça palavras python

Tags: python-3.x

Gente, estou tentando fazer um caça palavras.
As primeiras linhas devem conter letras com espaço em branco, depois falar o número de palavras e dizer qual a palavra.
A saída devera conter o diagrama com a palavra encontrada, substituindo o resto das letras por ".", e dizer quantas vezes as palavras apareceram.

No total tenho 3 erros no meu código( se não, mais).
Meu código é o seguinte:

```py
l = input()
d= []
l_palavras=[]
palavras=[]

while not l.isdigit():
  l= l.split()
  coluna= len(l)
  d.append(l)
  l = input()

linha= len(d)
n_palavras= int(l)

d2 = [['.' for j in range(coluna)] for i in range(linha)]


for i in range(0,n_palavras):
  palavras= list(input())
  l_palavras +=[palavras]



for m in range(0,n_palavras):


#NORTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i-k][j] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i
          achou= True


#SUL

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i+k][j] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i 
          achou= True 


#OESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i][j-k] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i
          achou= True


#LESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i][j+k] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i
          achou= True  


#NOROESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i-k][j+k] = l_palavras[m][k]  

          k= i
          achou= True  


#NORDESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i-k][j-k] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i
          achou= True


#SUDOESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i+k][j-k] = l_palavras[m][k]

          k= i
          achou= True


#SUDESTE

    for i in range(0,linha):
      for j in range(0,coluna):

        if l_palavras[m][0] == d[i][j]:    
          achou = True
          k = i

          for l in l_palavras[m]:
            if k < 0 or d[k][j] != l:
              achou = False
              break
            k = k - 1

          if achou:
            for k in range(len(l_palavras[m])):
              d2[i+k][j+k] = l_palavras[m][k]




for i in range(len(d2)):
  for j in range(len(d2[i])):
    print(d2[i][j], end=' ')
  print()
```

meu problema é o seguinte, tenho vários caça palavras com vários formatos,por exemplo, quando coloco esse caça palavras:

```
g z h y z l y n s g q j u
i n w a k b n x w w t n y
i w o u i p o f d b o y o
m k o h k l h r k h j w u
j l i o t r t c t b c o p
a h e d n y y y e g t p t
f n o h t y p y t h o n f
r l q o s y y y h n a f x
c e z x t k t m t x e u z
t g m h c v h x c h j n a
s n o w t q o b v n o z j
u n u x x a n p u i g n b
s i x o d j v s f e o n z
1
python
```

a saída é essa(a que realmente deveria ser):

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. n . . . . n . . . . n .
. . o . . . o . . . o . .
. . . h . . h . . h . . .
. . . . t . t . t . . . .
. . . . . y y y . . . . .
. n o h t y p y t h o n .
. . . . . y y y . . . . .
. . . . t . t . t . . . .
. . . h . . h . . h . . .
. . o . . . o . . . o . .
. n . . . . n . . . . n .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
python: 8
```

Mas, quando eu mudo a palavra a ser procurada, por exemplo:
**thon**

```
g z h y z l y n s g q j u
i n w a k b n x w w t n y
i w o u i p o f d b o y o
m k o h k l h r k h j w u
j l i o t r t c t b c o p
a h e d n y y y e g t p t
f n o h t y p y t h o n f
r l q o s y y y h n a f x
c e z x t k t m t x e u z
t g m h c v h x c h j n a
s n o w t q o b v n o z j
u n u x x a n p u i g n b
s i x o d j v s f e o n z
1
thon
```

como saída aparece:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . n . . n . . n . . .
. . . . o . o . o . . . .
. . . . . h h h . . . . .
. . . n o h t h o n . . .
. . . . . h h h . . . . .
. . . . o . o . o . . . .
. . . n . . n . . n . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

se eu tento outro caça palavras, por exemplo:

```
t c b i n t r o d u c a o
s a m b h r u o u f m e g
a l g o r i t m o z f x j
h k p r o g j c h m l h f
j s f w g p r o g r a m a
m a q j q q p v e w v g p
3
algoritmo
programa
introducao
```

A saida aparece apenas os pontos:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

outro problema que encontrei, é quando tento esse caça palavras, aparece um erro:

```
l c n x i s u p i i
t u u e z a q s n i
o q s t i m a i o r
o a l e c n s w h s
f t a l e i r f t c
e e g c t f b m y j
s a m a r g o r p i
c b a r e m t j r a
2
programa
python
```

esse é o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
    d2[i+k][j] = l_palavras[m][k]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Isso significa que ou o i+k,  j, m ou k estão passando do tamalnho da  lista (o que não necessariamente tem a ver com a questão dos pontos). Seria interessante simplificar a postagem ou fornecer um [mcve] para ficar mais viável ajuda. Tente imprimir os valores na tela dentro desse loop pra ver qual deles está "estourando"

Comment: Eu fui o mais detalhado possível.Como sou novo, não sei como reduzir o meu código, desculpe.Sobre o código, mesmo que eu conserte esse erro, que está fora do range, ele imprimir esse caça palavras como pontinhos igual ao outro, não vai?

Comment: Ta bem detalhada sim (melhor que a média inclusive), mas é que tá misturando situações diferentes e ficou complexo pelo excesso de código. O ideal mesmo seria você testar cada bloco separadamente e corrigir um por um (fazer funcionar o que pega as palavras na horizontal, depois fazer só o que pega na horizontal invertida, etc). Acho que facilitaria seu debug. Testar com um caça palavras menor ajudaria a ter menos output na tela tambem. Sobre os ranges, o print ajudaria você localizar o problema (mas isso falo independente do post aqui no SOpt).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/70

Comment: Tentarei arrumar o problema do range primeiro então, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: E experimente fazer funcionar cada eixo separadamente, depois vc junta num código só. Provavelmente depois de entender bem o range e cada eixo, vai conseguir simplificar o código e diminuir as repetições  reaproveitando o loop interno

Comment: É que eu fiquei muito curioso, por funcionar apenas no primeiro caça palavras perfeitamente, e no resto aparecer só os pontos.

Comment: Na primeira mudança de palavra pra thon, o resultado veio correto... trouxe as palavras de trás pra frente e na direção inicial....