# Erro: stack smashing detected

Tags: c++, memória, stack, g++

Estou tendo o erro:

> *** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated no meu programa

Uso o compilador g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, aqui está o código:

```
#include    &lt;iostream&gt;

using namespace std;

int main()<br>
{
    int C[3], F[3];<br>
    int Ct,Ft;<br>


    cin >> C[3] >> F[3];

    Ct = (C[1] * 3)+C[2];
    Ft = (F[1] * 3)+F[2];

    if ((Ct > Ft) || (Ct == Ft && C[3] > F[3]))
    {
        /* code */
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }else if ((Ft > Ct) || (Ft == Ct && F[3] > C[3]))
    {
        /* code */
        cout << "F" << endl;
    }else
    {
        cout << "=" << endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```

A entrada que coloco é : 10 5 18 11 1 18, deveria retornar C, mas ele retorna F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse código não faz sentido. Está declarando dois *arrays* (do jeito do C e não do jeito do C++) com tamanho 3 cada. Então os elementos vão do 0 ao 2 em cada.

Em seguida manda ler dados no console e manda guardar na posição 3 de cada *array*, só que essa posição não está reservado para ele, então está esmagando a pilha onde deveria ficar esse dado. Pode não dar problema em alguma situação, mas poderia dar em outra, é perigoso. Provavelmente queria guardar o dado na posição 2, que é a última.

Depois pega dados contidos na posição e 1 e 2 do *array*, provavelmente queria pegar a 0 e 1. Mas mesmo que conserte isso ainda é um problema porque essas posições não foram inicializadas, então pegará lixo da memória e o cálculo provavelmente dará o resultado errado.

Além de resolver o [problema do limite do *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101) precisaria resolver a questão conceitual do cálculo.

Comment: Poxa obrigado, tinha esquecido que os arrays começão em 0, fiz as correções e consegui.