# Problema na verificação de um for percorrendo uma array

Tags: java, array, for

Estava fazendo um jogo da velha bem simples até, e o mesmo feito, queria deixar a verificação de vitória automática, pois estava com muito "hard-code". A forma que eu achei para fazer isso, foi rodando um for, e sempre quando ele atingisse o max-length do array, ele mudaria de linha, mas não está funcionando como eu previ. Observação: o print do "K" foi só para verificar se o if estava funcionando.

```
    /*Verificação de vitória em vertical*/
                int k = 0;
                vitoriaX = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i <= tabuleiro.length  ; i++) {



                    if(tabuleiro[i][k].equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {

                        vitoriaX++;

                        if(vitoriaX == tabuleiro.length) {
                            validacao = true;
                            i = 2 + (tabuleiro.length);
                            }   
                        }   
                    if(i == tabuleiro.length) {
                        i = 0;
                        k++;    
                        vitoriaX = 0;
                        System.out.print(k);

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que deu para inferir, seu tabuleiro é um array de array de strings (`String[][]`). E como é um jogo da velha, então ele é 3x3.

Ou seja, ele é um array de 3 elementos, e cada elemento é um array com 3 strings.

Um dos problemas no seu código é que você não está considerando que arrays são indexados em zero. Ou seja, a primeira posição é 0, a segunda é 1, etc. Se os seus arrays tem 3 elementos, então os índices vão de 0 a 2.

Por isso fazer `i <= tabuleiro.length` no `for` está errado. O correto seria `i < tabuleiro.length`, pois `length` dá o tamanho do array (que no caso é 3), então `i` não pode valer 3, senão [ocorrerá um erro ao acessar este índice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/112052).

---

Enfim, uma forma de verificar é ter um array com as posições vencedoras. Aí basta verificar se todos os elementos destas posições são iguais - e se forem, temos um vencedor.

Lembrando que se o tabuleiro é um array de arrays, as posições seriam assim:

```
 (0, 0) | (0, 1) | (0, 2)
--------|--------|-------
 (1, 0) | (1, 1) | (1, 2)
--------|--------|-------
 (2, 0) | (2, 1) | (2, 2)
```

Para saber se alguém ganhou, preciso verificar as linhas, colunas e diagonais. Ficaria assim:

```
String[][] tabuleiro = {
    { "x", "o", "x" },
    { "x", "o", "o" },
    { "x", "", "" }
};
int[][][] posicoesVencedoras = {
  // horizontais
  { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 } }, { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 } }, { { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 } },
  // verticais
  { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 } }, { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 } }, { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 } },
  // diagonais
  { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } }, { { 0, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } }
};
String vencedor = null;
for (int[][] posicoes : posicoesVencedoras) {
    int p1[] = posicoes[0], p2[] = posicoes[1], p3[] = posicoes[2];
    if (tabuleiro[p1[0]][p1[1]].equalsIgnoreCase(tabuleiro[p2[0]][p2[1]]) && tabuleiro[p1[0]][p1[1]].equalsIgnoreCase(tabuleiro[p3[0]][p3[1]])) {
        vencedor = tabuleiro[p1[0]][p1[1]];
        break; // se achou um vencedor, não precisa verificar o resto
    }
}
if (vencedor != null)
    System.out.println("Vencedor: " + vencedor);
```

As posições vencedoras são um array, sendo que cada elemento é outro array, que por sua vez contém 3 arrays (e cada um desses contém as posições da linha e coluna a serem verificadas).

Para cada uma dessas combinações, eu verifico se as 3 posições são iguais. Se forem, temos um vencedor.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Muito obrigado! Foi bem esclarecedor e intuitivo seu código.

Comment: @Junior3874 Atualizei a resposta, tinha uns erros em alguns índices de `posicoesVencedoras` (já corrigi o código)