# Multiplicar uma matriz por um vetor

Tags: java, array, matriz

Preciso fazer um programa que multiplique uma matriz 3x3 por um vetor 3, e armazenar o resultado em um novo vetor. Porém não consigo o resultado e o problema provavelmente está na multiplicação.

```
 public  static  void  main ( String [] args ) {
    int[] vetor = new int[3];
    int[] vetor2 = new int[3];
    int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
    int i;
    int j;

    //Atribui um valor
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Numeros do vetor: ");
    for(i = 0; i < vetor.length ; i++)
    vetor[i] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Numeros da matriz: ");
    for(i = 0; i < matriz.length ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < matriz[i].length ; j++)
            matriz[i][j] = input.nextInt();

    }
    input.close();
    
    System.out.println("Tamanho do vetor: " + vetor.length);
    System.out.println("Tamanho da mariz: " + matriz.length);
    
    //Multiplica
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        vetor2[i] = vetor[i] * matriz[i][j];
    }

    //Exibe os valores multiplicados
    System.out.printf("\nValores Multiplicados \n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        System.out.printf("%d ",vetor2[i]);
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Só pra constar que a resposta do Adriano está errada (e a outra do le314u também). Por coincidência ela funciona em alguns casos, mas troque o vetor para `{1, 2, 3}` e dará errado: [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/b35DDM) que dá `{6, 30, 72}`, mas o [resultado correto](https://bit.ly/3ijUzZW) é `{14, 32, 50}`. Isso acontece porque deveria ser usado `vetor[j]` em vez de `vetor[i]` na multiplicação. E ela também não considera os casos em que a matriz não é quadrada. Por favor veja [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467472/112052) para uma solução mais geral (e correta).

Answer (score 1):

Dada uma matriz M x N (M linhas e N colunas) e um vetor com N elementos, o resultado da multiplicação é um vetor com **M** elementos, e [o algoritmo para se multiplicar a matriz pelo vetor](https://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication) é:

| matriz A | vetor x | multiplicação (matriz * vetor) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `A[1,1] A[1,2] ... A[1,N]` | `x[1]` | `A[1,1] * x[1] + A[1,2] * x[2] + ... + A[1,N] * x[N]` |
| `A[2,1] A[2,2] ... A[2,N]` | `x[2]` | `A[2,1] * x[1] + A[2,2] * x[2] + ... + A[2,N] * x[N]` |
| ... | ... | ... |
| `A[M,1] A[M,2] ... A[M,N]` | `x[N]` | `A[M,1] * x[1] + A[M,2] * x[2] + ... + A[M,N] * x[N]` |

Repare que cada elemento do resultado é a soma de várias operações. Mas no `for` que faz a multiplicação, você está sobrescrevendo o valor de `vetor2[i]`, em vez de ir somando ao valor já existente.

Outro detalhe é que não precisa declarar todas as variáveis no início do programa. Você pode declará-las mais próximas de onde serão usadas, e - na minha opinião - isso deixa o código um pouco mais claro (em códigos pequenos assim não faz tanta diferença, mas em códigos maiores ajuda bastante). Inclusive as variáveis dos *loops* podem ser declaradas dentro do próprio `for`.

E no caso específico do [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in), não precisa fechá-lo (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](/a/380458/112052) e [aqui](/a/380696/112052)).

Resumindo, ficaria assim:

```
int[] vetor = new int[3];
int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];

// ler os dados com o Scanner
...

// quantidade de elementos do resultado = quantidade de linhas da matriz
int[] resultado = new int[matriz.length];
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { // para cada linha da matriz
    for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) { // cada elemento da linha, multiplicado por um elemento do vetor
        resultado[i] += vetor[j] * matriz[i][j]; // soma ao resultado
    }
}

// não precisa usar printf se não tem variáveis a serem impressas, use println mesmo
System.out.println("\nValores Multiplicados");
for (int n : resultado) { // se eu só quero os valores, não precisa do índice
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}
```

Quando eu inicializo o array `resultado` com `new int[matriz.length]`, por padrão [os seus elementos já serão zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). E eu uso `matriz.length`, pois o tamanho do resultado é a quantidade de linhas da matriz.

Depois, dentro do `for`, eu atualizo o valor de cada elemento, somando ao valor atual (é isso que o operador `+=` faz). Repare também que usei `vetor[j]`, e não `vetor[i]` como você estava fazendo, pois assim o cálculo fica correto.

As outras respostas (uma foi apagada) estão usando `vetor[i]` em vez de `vetor[j]`, e com isso o resultado fica errado. Por exemplo, se a matriz e o vetor forem:

```
int[][] matriz = new int[][] {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};
int[] vetor = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

O resultado deve ser o vetor `{14, 32, 50}` ([confira aqui](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix%20multiplication%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22MatricesOperations%22%2C%20%22theMatrix2%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B1%2C%202%2C%203%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22MatricesOperations%22%2C%20%22theMatrix1%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B4%2C5%2C6%7D%2C%7B7%2C8%2C9%7D%7D%22)). Mas o código das outras respostas dá `{6, 30, 72}` (isso porque eles estão usando `vetor[i]` em vez de `vetor[j]` na multiplicação, mas segundo o algoritmo acima, vemos que é o valor da coluna que importa neste cálculo).

Outro detalhe é que as outras respostas não consideram os caso em que a matriz não é quadrada. Por exemplo, se ela for `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` (2 linhas e 3 colunas), o resultado deve ser um vetor com **2** elementos (usando o mesmo vetor acima, [o resultado deve ser `{14, 32}`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix%20multiplication%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22MatricesOperations%22%2C%20%22theMatrix2%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B1%2C%202%2C%203%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22MatricesOperations%22%2C%20%22theMatrix1%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B4%2C5%2C6%7D%7D%22)). Mas uma das respostas considerou que o resultado tem o mesmo tamanho do `vetor` de entrada (ou seja, 3), e com isso ele terá uma posição a mais - talvez esse detalhe tenha passado despercebido porque a matriz é quadrada, mas de qualquer forma, ambas dão resultados errados, e dependendo de como você fizer o código, pode até dar [esse erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/112052).

---

Para imprimir os valores, usei um [*enhanced for*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), pois se eu só quero imprimir os valores, não preciso de uma variável para controlar o índice (mas claro que você também poderia usar um `for (int i = 0; etc)` ou [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)), como sugeriu a outra resposta - mas isso é um detalhe, pois o que importava mesmo aqui é o algoritmo correto para fazer a multiplicação).

Lembrando que o código não verifica se a matriz e o vetor têm dimensões compatíveis, e nem se a matriz é de fato uma matriz (se todas as linhas têm o mesmo número de colunas, pois na verdade o que temos é um array de arrays, e nada garante que todos têm o mesmo tamanho, isso é algo que você tem que garantir à parte). Claro que neste caso específico os tamanhos estão corretos, mas o código acima não serviria para algo mais geral que aceitasse quaisquer arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Matriz (3x3)  * Vetor (3x1) = vetor(3x1)

No seu codigo durante a multiplicação no `for` de indice `j`  ou seja o for mais interno você passa nele 3 vezes e sobrescreve 3 vezes salvando apenas o valor de `vetor2[i] = vetor[i] * matriz[i][2]`

Ao em vez de fazer :

```
vetor2[i] = vetor[i] * matriz[i][j];
```

você deveria  primeiro inicializar o vetor2 com 0's e fazer

```
vetor2[i] = vetor2[i] + vetor[i] * matriz[i][j];
```

ou seja

> resultado[0] = (matriz[0][0] * vetor[0]) + (matriz[0][1] * vetor[1]) + (matriz[0][2] * vetor[2])

Comment: menos verboso:

`vetor2[i] += vetor[i] * matriz[i][j];`

Comment: porque negativou minha resposta?