# Erro Exception in thread "main" no Netbeans

Tags: java

Eu estava fazendo um código no Netbeans:

package calculadora;

public class Calculadora {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int x = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
 int y = Integer.parseInt(args [2]);
 sum(x, y);
}
static void sum(int x, int y){
    System.out.println( x + y);
}
```

}

Quando fui executar apareceu este erro:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1**

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que ocorre e como resolver um erro de "out of bounds" ou "out of range" ou algo de tipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411417/por-que-ocorre-e-como-resolver-um-erro-de-out-of-bounds-ou-out-of-range-ou-a)

Answer (score 0):

Tem certeza que a posição que você pegou é a certa? As arrays em java começam pelo índice 0.

Tente isso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
 int y = Integer.parseInt(args [1]);
 sum(x, y);
}
static void sum(int x, int y){
    System.out.println( x + y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode verificar os dados antes de chamar a função.

```
package calculadora;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculadora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double valor1;
        double valor2;

        if (args.length == 2) {
            valor1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            valor2 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        } else {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
            valor1 = scanner.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Digite o segundo valor: ");
            valor2 = scanner.nextDouble();
        }

        somar(valor1, valor2);
    }

    private static void somar(double valor1, double valor2) {
        System.out.println(valor1 + valor2);
    }
}
```

No caso aqui, eu programei para solicitar os dados para o usuário, caso eles não tenham sido informados na chamada do programa. Você também poderia mostrar uma mensagem de erro, enfim são várias opções.

Answer (score 0):

@Israel Messias além do que já foi falado vc esta executando essa aplicação a partir do terminal? Por que esses argumentos só vão ser passados se você informar no comando pelo terminal entende. Ou pela própria IDE

Exemplo pelo terminal

C:\App\target> java -jar nome_do_app.jar ARGUMENTO_1 ARGUMENTO_2

Pelo netbeans tem como fazer isso não precisa do Cmd do windows ou terminal do linux