# Erro na criação de um metodo recursivo

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, recursão, syntax-error

Olá tenho esse exercicio para resolver, e estou com um problema na resolução.

Crie um método recursivo que procure um número dentro de um vetor, a partir de um índice. Se achar o mesmo, o método retorna o índice em que ele se encontra, senão, retorna -1 (busca linear recursiva).
Esse é o código que fiz, mas não estou enxergando o erro, alguem pode dar uma luz aí:

```
public class BuscaSequencial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vetor = {9, 15, 7, 18, 23, 1, 75, 14, 54, 17, 21};
    int indice = buscaSequencial(vetor, 23, 0);
    System.out.println(indice);
}

private static int buscaSequencial(int[] vetor, int elemento, int i) {
    if (elemento != vetor[i]) {
        return buscaSequencial(vetor, elemento, i + 1);
    }else if(i > vetor.length - 1){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return i;
    }
}
```

}

Ele apenas funciona quando tem o elemento no vetor, mas quando o elemento não no vetor ele da o erro ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seu erro é quando você faz a chamada recursiva você verifica o valor no indice do array ao invez de verifcar o tamanho
ou seja chega um ponto no seu codigo onde a posição do indice é maior do que o tamanho do seu array ele ira dar uma execação.
o ideal seria voce inverter o seu if com o seu else if que ira resolver

```java
public class BuscaSequencial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vetor = {9, 15, 7, 18, 23, 1, 75, 14, 54, 17, 21};
    int indice = buscaSequencial(vetor, 23, 0);
    System.out.println(indice);
}

private static int buscaSequencial(int[] vetor, int elemento, int i) {
     //invertendo o else if com if faz ele verificar o tamanho do array antes
    // de tentar acessar a posicao
     if(i > vetor.length - 1){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (elemento != vetor[i]) {
        return buscaSequencial(vetor, elemento, i + 1);
    else{
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui, e funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda Jhonathan

Comment: `if(i >= vetor.length)` ficaria melhor :)

Comment: Se o colega deu uma resposta e é a solução do problema, por favor aceite a resposta dele.