# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, get

estou usando getx, Hasura e o firebase auth para autenticação. Antes do null safety, meu código estava funcionando normalmente, mas agora o sistema não consegue pegar o valor do uid do firebase de primeira. Vou mostrar o código e explicar o problema:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
Rxn<User> _firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
String get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email ?? '';
String get imageurl =>_firebaseUser.value?.photoURL ?? '';
String get uid => _firebaseUser.value?.uid ?? '';
final _authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
RxList<Usuario> listaUsuario = <Usuario>[].obs;

var nome = ''.obs;
var sobrenome = ''.obs;

@override
  void onInit() async {
  _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
  listaUsuario.assignAll(await _authService.getUsuario(uid));
  nome.value = listaUsuario[0].nome ?? '';
  sobrenome.value = listaUsuario[0].sobrenome ?? '';

}
```

Quando eu chamo o método listaUsuario, ele não consegue pegar o valor do uid inicialmente, apenas pega o valor como '', que é o valor que tive que colocar para não ser nulo. Como se ele executasse o código antes de pegar o valor da uid.
Se eu chamar o método duas vezes, ele funciona, e pega normalmente o código na segunda execução.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101

Answer (score 0):

Não é recomendado o uso de `async / await` dentro do método `onInit()`.
Você pode tentar solucionar seu problema de duas formas:

- Colocar seu código em uma função assíncrona fora do método `onInit()` e chamá-la lá dentro:

```dart
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
    Rxn<User> _firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
    String get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email ?? '';
    String get imageurl =>_firebaseUser.value?.photoURL ?? '';
    String get uid => _firebaseUser.value?.uid ?? '';
    final _authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
    RxList<Usuario> listaUsuario = <Usuario>[].obs;

    var nome = ''.obs;
    var sobrenome = ''.obs;

    void inicializacao() async {
      _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
      listaUsuario.assignAll(await _authService.getUsuario(uid));
      nome.value = listaUsuario[0].nome ?? '';
      sobrenome.value = listaUsuario[0].sobrenome ?? '';
    }

    @override
      void onInit() {
          super.initState(); // Isso está faltando no seu código.    
          inicializacao();
    }
```

ou

- Fazendo chamadas dos objetos que dependem da rede dentro do método `.then()` de cada Future na funcão `onInit()`, de forma aninhada. Por exemplo:

```dart
...
_authService.getUsuario(uid).then((){
    listaUsuario.assignAll();
    ...
})
...
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).