# Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java, array

```
 Olá, colegas.
 Ficaria muito grato se me ajudassem a compreender este erro.
 Entendo que tem a ver com tamanho de array.
 Fiz o meu código, um pouco diferente do da professora: deu erro. Depois de muito vasculhar e não sair do lugar, copiei e colei o dela: também deu erro.
 Estou começando Java agora, e quando o código da professora deu erro... putz.
```

(Obs: faculdade EAD - aguardo retorno há 2 dias).

````
    ```
    class Programa01
    {
        public static void main (String entrada[])
        {
            int NumInt;
            double NumReal, soma;
            char Caracter;
    
            NumInt = Integer.parseInt(entrada[0]);
            NumReal = Double.parseDouble(entrada[1]);
            Caracter = (entrada[2]).charAt(0);
    
            soma = (double)NumInt + NumReal;
    
            System.out.println((double)NumInt + " + " + NumReal + " = " + soma + " sinal " + Caracter);

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Como você executa o codigo? Porque do jeito q ele ta escrito, vc teria q passar um array na linha de execucao, ou terá um array vazio, conforme o erro acusa.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(O código está teoricamente correto, o único erro possível é na altura de executar o programa, em que é necessario executar com 3 parametros. Pelo nome da sua pergunta presumo que apenas tenha feito: "java (nome do programa)"
Em vez de fazer: "java (nome do programa) (parametro 1) (parametro 2) (parametro 3)"
)

Existe apenas uma coisa que o pode impedir de receber tal erro, por uma guarda para só executar o código caso o programa tenha a quantidade de parametros correta.

```
class Programa01
    {
        public static void main (String entrada[])
        {
            if(entrada.length != 3) {
               System.out.println("É necessário 3 parametros para executar este programa.");
               System.out.println("Depois de compilar experimente executar o programa seguindo este exemplo: java (nome do programa) (parametro 1 ou seja aquilo que se vai tornar em numInt) (parametro 2 ou seja aquilo que se vai tornar em numReal) (parametro 3 ou seja aquilo que se vai tornar em caracter)");
            }
            else {
               int numInt;
               double numReal, soma;
               char caracter;
    
               NumInt = Integer.parseInt(entrada[0]);
               NumReal = Double.parseDouble(entrada[1]);
               Caracter = (entrada[2]).charAt(0);
    
               soma = (double)NumInt + NumReal;
    
               System.out.println((double)NumInt + " + " + NumReal + " = " + soma + " sinal " + Caracter);
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Nota:
Por norma os nomes das variaveis devem começar com letra minuscula exemplo: `soma` em vez de `Soma`. Apenas depois, para melhorar separar os nomes das variaveis é que se uma a letra maiuscula, exemplo: `somaDeNumeros` em vez de `somadenumeros`.

Espero que tenha ajudado, bom trabalho!

Answer (score -3):

voce esta ececutando passando os argumentos? tipo: java -jar programa 1 2 3
porque se nao a array vai ficar vazia e vai dar erro

o que voce pode tentar é invez de receber a variavel via argumentos, criar as variaveis localmente por exemplo:

String[] Entrada = {"10.0", "+", "1,0"}

Comment: Depois de escrito no editor, salvo como .java    Compilo: javac *.java para criar o bytecode. Até aí, sem problemas. Mas quando executo (java *), retorna esse erro.